# Change DateTime separator

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in ASP.NET and I want to change format for DateTime variable. Her my code in model file:

```
...
namespace ProjectMVC.Models
{
    public class EventDetails
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd.mm.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
}
```

and in view:

```
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventDate, "Event begin date")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EventDate, "", new { onblur = "IsEmptyField(this)" })
        </div>
```

How can i use "." separator for storing and checking data?

Answer (score 0):

Use an EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor if you want this DisplayFormat attribute to be respected:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EventDate)
```

and if you wanted to attach some javascript to this element, do it unobtrusively, for example:

```
<div class="eventDate">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EventDate)
</div>
```

and then in your separate js file:

```
$('.eventDate input').blur(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Why you recommend use a wrapper to apply css or js on it instead of using the htmlatributes dictionary?

Comment: Oh there's an `htmlatributes` dictionary? They finally introduced that? By the time I was doing ASP.NET MVC there wasn't such property. But if they introduced it, obviously it should be used instead of a wrapper class. Feel free to update my answer (don't forget to specify the MVC version for which this applies as well because if someone is using an older version it won't work).

Comment: The problem is that the model unerstand on this date fotmat: 11/11/1111 but i want 11.11.1111. How to fix it?

Comment: @dantey89 You set `ApplyFormatInEditMode = false` you need to set to `true` in order to apply that format in edit mode (use of EditorFor) if you only need to display it, use `DisplayFor` instead.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov OMG! My bad! I was thinking on TextBoxFor not on EditorFor. Forget what I said!